# PHP vsprintf with arguments

Tags: php

I have the following class:

```
<?php 
    class L {
        const login = 'Login';
        const title_404 = '404';
        const title_dyn = 'Title: %s';
        const page_dyn = 'Page: %s - %s';

        public static function __callStatic($string, $args) {
           vsprintf(constant("self::" . $string), $args);
        }
    }
```

It won't replace %s by passed arguments:

```
    L::login; --> Login
    L::title_404; --> 404
    L::title_dyn('test'); --> empty
    L::page_dyn('test', 'more'); --> empty
    L::login(); --> empty
```

I should get with L::title_dyn('test'); --> "Title: test"

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The first two lines will not call `__callStatic` as they are not calling functions, they are accessing properties of the class. Other three are working if `echo` is added in front of `vsprintf`

Comment: @Cheery Thank you, I really forgot the echo in front of vsprintf. It's time for a break :)

Comment: @nenad007: `echo` is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably your full testcase is something like this:

```
<?php 
class L {
    const login = 'Login';
    const title_404 = '404';
    const title_dyn = 'Title: %s';
    const page_dyn = 'Page: %s - %s';

    public static function __callStatic($string, $args) {
       vsprintf(constant("self::" . $string), $args);
    }
}

echo L::login . "\n";                    // "Login"
echo L::title_404 . "\n";                // "404"
echo L::title_dyn('test') . "\n";        // (empty)
echo L::page_dyn('test', 'more') . "\n"; // (empty)
echo L::login() . "\n";                  // (empty)
```

<sup>(next time, write this in the question please)</sup>

The first two work because you're not using function-call syntax, so the constants are `echo`'d as-is.

The latter three are empty because, although `__callStatic` does its work, it then completely discards that work: *you never return the result of `vsprintf`*. Recall that `vsprintf` does not output anything — it *returns* its result. You also did not write any `echo` in there. So, there is no value for your calling code to use, and no output from within the function itself. Presto, just as your problem says.

You almost certainly want to do this:

```
    public static function __callStatic($string, $args) {
       return vsprintf(constant("self::" . $string), $args);
    }
```

#### Live demos: [broken](http://ideone.com/y5zAzO), [working](http://ideone.com/Ozo1Xu)

Comment: I switched to this answer, as it completely explain my Issue and you catch correctly that I don't returned the value (had changed from vprintf to vsprintf and forgot about).